# Complex-Valued input to CNN

Tags: tensorflow, cnn

I want to train a CNN. However, my input is images of size 100*100 with complex numbers. I have runned the model, but it failed and the loss didn't decrease. Then I found out that my because my inputs are complex, they are not able to train very good. Actually, I think the activation functions and the convolutions and the optimizer, backpropagation, cost should be changed. I wonder how I can Implement my CNN with Complex-Valued input. I would be thankful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been some research in building very specialized deep learning models to use complex numbers using complex algebra, but these tools are not yet user-friendly. So unless you want to go down the rabbit hole and try to understand their implementations and then try to write your own implementation, i would avoid this.

In the past, I worked with MRI data which is a 3D complex-valued matrix. I inspired myself from the work done in color images, where 3 channels are used to represent red (R), green (G) and blue (B). I this separated the real and imaginary part, and treated them as separate channels into the deep learning model all as real numbers.

1D example:

From a complex vector, we get 2 channels where the imaginary part can then be treated as a real number.

$[1+1j, 2+2j, 3+3j] = [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]$

Comment: Thank You very much for your response. I just have another question. As I told before, My data are images of size 100*100 complex number. and my labels are images of size 100*100 double number. If I put the real part on channel 1 and the imaginary part on channel 2, how I can compare the input data of size 100*100*2 with the label of size 100*100*1 ??  
I'm using CNN for the regression task. 
Thanks for your response.